# Hist chart from list

Tags: python, list, numpy, matplotlib, math

```
import matplotlib as plp
cube = []
z = 0
while not z == 50:
    x = random.randint(1, 6)
    cube.append(x)
    z = z + 1
print(cube)
plp.plot(cube[1])
plp.show()
```

How to repair this code to show histogram from components include in my list cube?

Comment: Your import looks suspicious -- try ```import matplotlib.pyplot as plp```

Comment: To see the histogram: ```plp.hist(cube)```, followed by ```plp.show()```

Comment: what wrong with this code? Don't expect that we will run it to see problem.

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information.

Answer (score 0):

The comments do make some suggestions on most of the fixes you can make, but you can also improve this code alot in other ways. Here is what I would propose:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import random

cube = []
for _ in range(50):
    x = random.randint(1, 6)
    cube.append(x)

plt.hist(cube)
plt.show()
```

First, since you only use z as an iteration counter, a for loop is better here (though the while loop will still work, it is more error prone). I also changed plp to plt, you don't have to do this but this is the convention. You can then use plt.hist(cube) to plot a histogram.

Note that if you want to use numpy, you can make this even simpler:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

cube = np.random.randint(1, 6, size=50)

plt.hist(cube)
plt.show()
```

Since numpy lets you specify the size of the array of random numbers you want.